# how to limit puma memory usage and cpu usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

As title, Is it possible to limit puma servers max memory usage and CPU usage ?

Because there are many rails apps are running on my EC2 server

I need to limit each app's resource. To avoid some app's spend too much resources.

Answer (score 0):

For the CPU, you can try wrapping your workers inside https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit.